# FormatMessage with placeholders

Tags: c++, windows

```
CString ErrorMessageFromErrorCode(DWORD errorCode)
{
    void* pMsgBuf = NULL;

    ::FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
        NULL,
        errorCode,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &pMsgBuf,
        0,
        NULL);

    CString result;

    if ( pMsgBuf )
    {
        result = (LPTSTR) pMsgBuf;
        LocalFree(pMsgBuf);
    }

    if ( result.Length() == 0 )
        result = _T("Unknown error");


    return result;
}
```

When called with parameter 2, this function returns "The system cannot find the file specified.". When called with 0xC1, it returns "Unknown error". Microsoft Error Lookup utility shows this for 0xC1: "%1 is not a valid Win32 application.". So, when error message contains placeholder, my function doesn't work.
Is there generic way to get the same result as Error Lookup, without knowing anything about error code?

Comment: Parameter 2? You mean FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM? Looks like it was working and you had tried to open or delete a file that didn't exist previously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS` to the flags.

Comment: Obligatory reading: [The importance of the FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS flag](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/11/28/6564257.aspx)

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but I was wondering... is there a way to find out the value it wants? I mean, you just called some function that returned that error, and presumably there was some specific file it tried to load and found to not be a valid win32 application. For this particular error message it might be a string you passed to LoadLibrary, but for another one one of the placeholders is the serial number of the floppy disk you tried to access, etc.

Comment: @Random832: no, as far as I know, there's no way to have that.